# Django Admin: Filter Change List by Starting Letter

Tags: django, django-admin

A while ago, I found a filter for django admin that would allow you to set a field and filter the results of the admin change list based on what letter the value for that field started with.

So for example, if had a model with the field `city`, I could go into the admin and set to filter by `city`.

E.G.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ???? = ('city',)
    list_display = ('city', 'state', 'country',)
    list_filter = ('state',)
```

Once added, the change list would have...

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P ...

across the top of the page.

What is the name of the admin setting?

Comment: This is one way to achieve this: https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/